# GRU (Gated Recurrent Unit) presents errors with running out of data from a generator function and, no data provided for "each key in.." in R (RStudio)

Tags: r, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Starter here - no formal background in ML or anything close and a little self taught R. I am using RStudio to do this.
I have set up an elementary G.R.U. onto which I hope to build more process. My first follows the instruction on https://blogs.rstudio.com/tensorflow/posts/2017-12-20-time-series-forecasting-with-recurrent-neural-networks/, to use a generator function for training data and feed into `fit_generator()`. The second uses no generator and `fit.keras.engine.training.Model()`.
My settings at this point of trial and error are -
With generator function:

```
library(keras)

model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_gru(units = 5, input_shape = list(NULL, dim(data)[[-1]])) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1)

model %>% compile(
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
  loss = "mae"
)

history <- model %>% fit_generator(
  train_gen,
  steps_per_epoch = 100,
  epochs = 1,
  validation_data = val_gen,
  validation_steps = val_steps
)
```

With no generator function:

```
library(keras)

model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_gru(units = 32, input_shape = list(NULL, dim(data)[[-1]])) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1)

model %>% compile(
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
  loss = "mae"
)

history <- model %>% fit(
  x=train_data[,1:2],
  y=train_data[,3:4],
  epochs = 2,
  verbose=1,
  shuffle=F,
  validation_data = val_data[,1:4]
)
```

My data are the closing prices of currencies from mt4. To help understand my data the code looks so:

```
library(tibble)
library(readr)

data_dir <- "C:/Users/elech/Desktop/traindats"
USDCADname <- file.path(data_dir, c("USDCAD.csv"))
USDAUDname <- file.path(data_dir, c("USDAUD.csv"))
USDCHFname <- file.path(data_dir, c("USDCHF.csv"))
USDNZDname <- file.path(data_dir, c("USDNZD.csv"))
USDJPYname <- file.path(data_dir, c("USDJPY.csv"))

USDCAD<- read_csv(USDCADname, col_names = F)
USDAUD<- read_csv(USDAUDname, col_names = F)
USDCHF<- read_csv(USDCHFname, col_names = F)
USDNZD<- read_csv(USDNZDname, col_names = F)
USDJPY<- read_csv(USDJPYname, col_names = F)

Close_USDAUD<-USDAUD$X6
Close_USDCAD<-USDCAD$X6
Close_USDCHF<-USDCHF$X6
Close_USDNZD<-USDNZD$X6
Close_USDJPY<-USDJPY$X6

train_data<-data[1:2000,]
val_data<-data[2001:4000,]
test_data<-data[4001:nrow(data),]
data<-tibble(USDAUD=Close_USDAUD[176:5175], USDCAD=Close_USDCAD[173:5172], USDCHF=Close_USDCHF[176:5175], USDJPY=Close_USDJPY[175:5174], USDNZD=Close_USDNZD[170:5169])
```

I struggled with the input shape before I used the setup provided by [1](https://blogs.rstudio.com/tensorflow/posts/2017-12-20-time-series-forecasting-with-recurrent-neural-networks/), if I could additionally get help with setting up a functional input array that'd be great.
My results that need help have revolved around;

With generator:

```
Error occurred in generator: argument 'length.out' must be of length 1
WARNING:tensorflow:Your dataset iterator ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your iterator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 2000 batches). You may need touse the repeat() function when building your dataset.
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: Empty training data.
```

(The 'Detailed Traceback' left out )

Without generator (which ive decided to focus on):

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: No data provided for "gru_8_input". Need data for each key in: ['gru_8_input']
```

What is gru_8_input? Even Google doesn't know what it is!
Please help.

Plus,
The generator function is from [1](https://blogs.rstudio.com/tensorflow/posts/2017-12-20-time-series-forecasting-with-recurrent-neural-networks/).

Thanks.